# Wildfly 11 http to https redirecting losing http method

Tags: https, wildfly, wildfly-11

i configured my wildfly 11 installation with rewrite filters to redirect from http to https. As described there:
[Redirect http requests to https in wildfly 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752067/redirect-http-requests-to-https-in-wildfly-10)

```
<filters>
   <rewrite name="http-to-https" redirect="true" target="https://%v:443%U"/>
</filters>
```

And

```
<filter-ref name="http-to-https" predicate="equals(%p,80)"/>
```

This works perfectly for GET Requests, but if i try a POST request i get

```
405 Method not allowed
```

Does anybody know how to configure the rewrite filter to use the message type (%m, http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.4.0/index.html)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

POST redirects are not well supported.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295085/redirection-on-apache-maintain-post-params) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280361/nginx-loses-post-variable-with-http-https-redirect) as examples to handle this problem.

For Spring, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623807/spring-mvc-return-custom-http-status-code-no-error) shows a way to send back a different HTTP status than 301.

The short answer is that you need to use a different HTTP response code (308 Permanent Redirect).  The last answer shows a way to do that.

Comment: Thank you. We decided to see this as a feature to disable http POST request :D